# App Branching with Google Analytics 4: Got an exception while running a Xamarin Forms Android app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, branch.io

I am a Xamarin developer and I have followed the URL https://help.branch.io/partners-portal/docs/google-analytics-4#properties-sent-to-google-analytics to integrate Google Analytics 4 in Xamarin forms Android to send branch data to Google Analytics dashboard, but I got exception while running the app, saying

> BranchXamarinSDK.BranchException: you must initialize Branch before you can use the Branch object

I have implemented code below in MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 

base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); 

// Set the request metadata before initializing the Branch SDK 
BranchAndroid.GetInstance().SetRequestMetadata("$firebase_app_instance_id", (string) FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(this).GetAppInstanceId()); 
BranchAndroid.GetInstance().SetRequestMetadata("$firebase_user_id", "{user_id}"); 

BranchAndroid.Init(this, Resources.GetString(Resource.String.branch_test_key), this); 

LoadApplication(new App()); 

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please take the time to format your code so it is readable, and please do NOT post errors or code as images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want to call the `SetRequestMetadata()` method, the `BranchAndroid.GetInstance()` must have value or [it will be null](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/xamarin-branch-deep-linking-attribution/blob/dffb0fdf536ac8a716556913b428f4fe9e8ec002/Branch-Xamarin-SDK.Droid/BranchAndroid.cs#L26).

In addition, I have check the official document about the **Branch** and [the resource code about the BranchAndroid](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/xamarin-branch-deep-linking-attribution/blob/master/Branch-Xamarin-SDK.Droid/BranchAndroid.cs).

The official document said:

[image]

**So just make the `SetRequestMetadata()` called before the session initialization and after the instance initialization is ok.** Your code should be:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 

base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); 

BranchAndroid.Init(this, Resources.GetString(Resource.String.branch_test_key), this); 
// Set the request metadata before initializing the Session 
BranchAndroid.GetInstance().SetRequestMetadata("$firebase_app_instance_id", (string) FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(this).GetAppInstanceId()); 
BranchAndroid.GetInstance().SetRequestMetadata("$firebase_user_id", "{user_id}"); 
LoadApplication(new App()); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks Liyun, It has been resolved by the above-mentioned code, but is facing another challenge. This code is not working correctly; the branch data is not being sent to the Google Analytics dashboard. please check [link](https://help.branch.io/partners-portal/docs/google-analytics-4#properties-sent-to-google-analytics) to know the steps. thanks.

Comment: And you can post a new question to show the details about  **this code not working correctly**. @YashwantSinghRathore

Comment: Sure and can you please have a look why above code is not working.

Comment: I don't know what does the not working mean. Did you mean [Data not appearing in Google Analytics](https://help.branch.io/partners-portal/docs/google-analytics-4#data-not-appearing-in-google-analytics)? @YashwantSinghRathore

Comment: No, First of all, I need to make sure the request data will show up in Webhook records which is sent to GA4.

Comment: Sorry for that I have never used this and it seems you didn't init the session. You can checked the [official document about the branch for the xamarin.android](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/xamarin-android). @YashwantSinghRathore